# overloading >> operator for string class c++

Tags: c++, string, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a problem with overloading >> operator for string class;
here is my class:

```
class str
{
    char s[250];
    public:
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, str& a);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, str& a);
    friend str operator + (str a, str b);
    str * operator = (str a);
    friend int operator == (str a, str b);
    friend int operator != (str a, str b);
    friend int operator > (str a, str b);
    friend int operator < (str a, str b);
    friend int operator >= (str a, str b);
    friend int operator <= (str a, str b);
};
```

and here is overloaded operator:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, str& a)
{
    in>>a.s;
    return in;
}
```

the problem is that it reads the string only to first space(only one word from sentence).

I solved it. Found the answer on dreamincode :D

Comment: Re: "the problem is that it reads the string only to first space": Whereas you want it to read all the way to . . . what? (In other words: it's not clear what you're trying to do, so we can't really help you do it.)

Comment: for example: i want to read "This is sparta", it reads only "This"

Comment: @MihaiSvet, ruakh question was about how do you expect it to know it's enough.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/145699-eof-and-reading-text-files-c/

Comment: Isn't that just how `istream >>` works?

Comment: @Wug - thought so, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior for [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) is to read until the first whitespace character. Change your function to the following:

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, str& a)
{
    in.getline( a.s, sizeof(a.s) );
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works, you probably want to use [std::getline(std::istream&,std::string&) of std::getline(std::istream&,std::string&,char)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).

*edit*: others, suggesting `istream`'s `getline` are also right.

Answer (score 1):

The overloaded operator>>() for the istream class just takes the input till it finds any blank space (tab, newline, space characters). You need to use the getline method.

```
...
istream& operator >> (istream& in, str& a)
{
    in.getline(a.s, 250);
    return in;
}
...
```